# What is the correct way to raise an NSException?

Tags: objective-c, nsexception

I've created a macro that, if compiling in debug mode, will check to make sure the method has been called by a subclass with the same name (to stop external classes from calling it). If that is not the case, it will throw an exception:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

#define CHECK_INHERITANCE() \
do { \
    NSString *this = [NSThread callStackSymbols][0]; \
    NSString *parent = [NSThread callStackSymbols][1]; \
    NSError *error = NULL; \
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[\\w+ ((\\w+:)+)\\]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error]; \
    NSTextCheckingResult *resultThis = [regex firstMatchInString:this options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, this.length)]; \
    NSString *strThis = [this substringWithRange:[resultThis rangeAtIndex:1]]; \
    NSTextCheckingResult *resultParent = [regex firstMatchInString:parent options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, parent.length)]; \
    NSString *strParent = [parent substringWithRange:[resultParent rangeAtIndex:1]]; \
    if(![strThis isEqualToString:strParent]) [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Must be called from a subclass"]; \
} while (0);

#else

#define CHECK_INHERITANCE() //

#endif
```

I tested it and it works, but the `NSException` it throws doesn't give me any stack trace that would hint at why it crashed, nor does it show the message "*Must be called from a subclass*". I just get "`0 __kill`" on the main thread and a bunch of lines of assembler. How can I get it to throw me a more useful exception? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using an assertion instead of raise?

Comment: Not used NSAssert before. I just tried `NSAssert(NO, @"Must be called from a subclass");', and although I get an Assertion failure that tells me which line in code, I still don't get the message coming through.

Comment: Where + how are you trying to pick up the message / trace?

Comment: I would just like a runtime message to tell me what has happened, and for the program to abort. This is to stop people from calling the method directly from a class other than the subclass.

Comment: So the assertion should print the message you provide to the console.

Comment: It doesn't appear to for me. I just get `*** Assertion failure in -[ClassName functionName:], /Workspace/objc-project/Classes/View/Game/Slots/Base/ClassName.m:52`

Comment: Do you have an all exception breakpoint? Continue past it an you'll see: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must be called from a subclass'`

Comment: I do have an all exception breakpoint, but it is switched off. However, I discovered that if I pressed the 'Continue program execution' button after it gets to the Assertion failure line, I get the `Terminating app` message you mentioned. Why does it break on the Assertion failure and not the Terminating app message?

Comment: Also, if I switch it back to an `NSException`, I realise I get the same thing... If I press the continue button, it prints the exception comment. I wonder why I have to press the continue button...?

Comment: To let lldb print it. BTW: Your check with callstack symbols is no good idea, because it is fragile. Why do you have to check this? You can control the publicity of methods with Interfaces.

Comment: Just something I was experimenting with. An internal API that would force other devs to only call those methods from a subclass and nowhere else. Not sure if I'm going to keep it, but just wanted to work out how best to use NSException (or NSAssert).